# Redisson: WRITE_BIGDECIMAL_AS_PLAIN

Tags: java, redis, client

I just downloaded Redisson but I am continuously getting the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: WRITE_BIGDECIMAL_AS_PLAIN
    at org.redisson.codec.JsonJacksonCodec.<init>(JsonJacksonCodec.java:48)
    at org.redisson.Config.<init>(Config.java:44)
    at org.redisson.Redisson.create(Redisson.java:85)
```

It is probably something trivial but I did not find anything online.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use latest version of [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core) in classpath.

Comment: I tried 2.3.3, didn't help (with maven). How can I resolve this?

Comment: check your classpath, there is an old version of jackson lib