# Redisson NoSuchFieldError: WRITE_BIGDECIMAL_AS_PLAIN

Tags: java, maven, redis, client, jackson

I just imported redisson 1.0.3 via maven, set up a redis-server on localhost on default port and wanted to try the redisson redis client. My test code looks as following:

```
Redisson redis = Redisson.create();
Map m = redis.getMap("someMap");
```

But I'm getting:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: WRITE_BIGDECIMAL_AS_PLAIN
    at org.redisson.codec.JsonJacksonCodec.createObjectMapper(JsonJacksonCodec.java:90)
    at org.redisson.codec.JsonJacksonCodec.<init>(JsonJacksonCodec.java:43)
    at org.redisson.Config.<init>(Config.java:44)
    at org.redisson.Redisson.create(Redisson.java:85)
    at ...
```

As suggested in [Redisson: WRITE_BIGDECIMAL_AS_PLAIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21685247/redisson-write-bigdecimal-as-plain) I added the dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

But no change...
I guess redisson's dependencies are somehow broken but how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like my classpath already contained an older version of jackson, this fixed it:

```
    <!-- Redis deps -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
        <artifactId>redisson</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: take a look at pom.xml of redisson there is jackson-core:2.3.2 and jackson-databind 2.3.2