# Unable to validate schema with JSON Schema Validator, error occurs with JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault();

Tags: json, validation, jackson, schema

I'm using JSON Schema Validator (https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator) to validate the content of this simple object:

```
{
  "firstName": "Bob",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "age": 23
}
```

My schema is defined by:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string"
      },
      "lastName": {
      "type": "string"
      },
      "age": {
         "type": "integer"
      }
     }, 
     "required": ["firstName", "lastName", "age"]
}
```

I have written the following code to validate the object using the schema:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {      
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    // Create the source configuration file
    ObjectNode sourceConfig = mapper.createObjectNode();
    sourceConfig.put("firstName", "Bob");
    sourceConfig.put("lastName", "Smith");
    sourceConfig.put("age", 23);

    // Create the schema used for validation
    ObjectNode schema = mapper.createObjectNode();
    schema.put("$schema", "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#");
    schema.put("type", "object"); 

    ObjectNode properties = mapper.createObjectNode();

    ObjectNode firstName = mapper.createObjectNode();
    firstName.put("type", "string");
    properties.put("firstName", firstName);

    ObjectNode lastName = mapper.createObjectNode();
    lastName.put("type", "string");
    properties.put("lastName", lastName);

    ObjectNode age = mapper.createObjectNode();
    age.put("type", "integer");
    properties.put("age", age);

    List<String> required = new ArrayList<String>();
    required.add("firstName");
    required.add("lastName");
    required.add("age");

    // Convert the list to an arraynode and add to schema
    ArrayNode array = mapper.valueToTree(required);
    schema.putArray("required").addAll(array);
    schema.put("properties", properties);

    JsonSchemaFactory factory = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault();
    JsonSchema schemaValidation = null;

    try {
         schemaValidation = factory.getJsonSchema(schema);
    }

    catch (ProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ProcessingReport report = null;

    try {
        report = schemaValidation.validate(sourceConfig);
    } 

    catch (ProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the error that comes up when I run the program:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: WRITE_BIGDECIMAL_AS_PLAIN
    at com.github.fge.jackson.JacksonUtils.newMapper(JacksonUtils.java:155)
    at com.github.fge.jackson.JacksonUtils.<clinit>(JacksonUtils.java:55)
    at com.github.fge.jackson.JsonNodeReader.<init>(JsonNodeReader.java:82)
    at com.github.fge.jackson.JsonLoader.<clinit>(JsonLoader.java:50)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.SchemaVersion.<init>(SchemaVersion.java:63)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.SchemaVersion.<clinit>(SchemaVersion.java:44)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.load.configuration.LoadingConfigurationBuilder.<init>(LoadingConfigurationBuilder.java:117)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.load.configuration.LoadingConfiguration.byDefault(LoadingConfiguration.java:151)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchemaFactoryBuilder.<init>(JsonSchemaFactoryBuilder.java:67)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchemaFactory.newBuilder(JsonSchemaFactory.java:123)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault(JsonSchemaFactory.java:113)
    at PlayingWithJsonSchemaValidation.main(PlayingWithJsonSchemaValidation.java:114)
```

And when I ran the program through a debugger, an error occurred at JsonSchemaFactory factory = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault(); I'm not sure how to fix this error, or what exactly is wrong with the code. Could anybody please give me some tips on how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redisson NoSuchFieldError: WRITE\_BIGDECIMAL\_AS\_PLAIN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23083940/redisson-nosuchfielderror-write-bigdecimal-as-plain)